# How to save the checkbox state even after the page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox

I have  multiple checkboxes on my UI which when checked doing some operation. But the moment I refresh the page all the check boxes are unchecked again. How can I use AJS.Cookie (Atlassian Javascript framework) to save the state. Source Code which I have written but it gives the cookie value as undefined.

`'#generate-canvas-button'` is the id of the button which passes all the checked checkboxes.

```
// Wait until the page is completely loaded.
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
  // Iterating over all checkboxes on page.
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    // Getting checkbox name.
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    // Checking saved cookie.
    if (AJS.Cookie.read(name)) {
      // Updating checkbox state.
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });

  // Clicking the OK button should run submit(), pop up displays all checked boxes
  $('#generate-canvas-button').click(submit);
});

function submit() {
  var checked = [];
  var targetGroupActors = [];
  var bigPictureActors = [];
  var bigPictureImpacts = [];
  var productDetailsActors = [];
  var productDetailsDeliverable = [];

  // Iterating over all checkboxes on page.
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    // Getting checkbox name.
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    // Checking checkbox state.
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      // Saving checkbox name to cookie.
      AJS.Cookie.save(name, true);
    } else {
      // Remove checkbox state from cookie.
      AJS.Cookie.erase(name);
    }

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      impactMapValues = $( this ).prop('id');
      impactMapActor = $( this ).prop('name');
      var value = document.getElementById(impactMapValues).value;

      if (impactMapActor == "actor-checkbox") {
        targetGroupActors.push(value);
      }

      if (impactMapActor == "impact-checkbox") {
          var result = value.split(",");
          actor_value = result[0];
          impact_value = result[1];
          bigPictureActors.push(actor_value);
          bigPictureImpacts.push(impact_value);
      }

      if (impactMapActor == "deliverable-checkbox") {
        var result = value.split(",");
        actor_value = result[0];
        deliverable_value = result[1];
        productDetailsActors.push(actor_value);
        productDetailsDeliverable.push(deliverable_value);
      }

      checked.push(value);
    }
  });

  addTotargetGroup(targetGroupActors);
  addToBigPicture(bigPictureActors,bigPictureImpacts);
  addReleaseTarget(productDetailsActors,productDetailsDeliverable);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this approach:

```
// Wait until the page is completely loaded.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Iterating over all checkboxes on page.
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    // Getting checkbox name.
    var name = $(this).attr('name');

    // Checking saved cookie.
    if (AJS.Cookie.read(name)) {
      // Updating checkbox state.
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }

    // Attaching onchange handler.
    $(this).change(function() {
      // Checking checkbox state.
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // Saving checkbox name to cookie.
        AJS.Cookie.save(name, true);
      } else {
        // Remove checkbox state from cookie.
        AJS.Cookie.erase(name);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I did try this but without $(document).ready(function() as I have the whole code inside a javascript file and it is not wroking. Using AJS.log(AJS.Cookie.save(name, true)); gives undefined.

Comment: @user_dev you should use `$(document).ready`. I've updated the comments in the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks Valetin , I am updating the code in the question with the complete code I have written.

Comment: @user_dev If you want to keep checkboxes states after reloading page you need to go through following flow:  
1. Wait until the page is completely loaded (e.g. `$(document).ready`);
2. Iterate over all checkboxes on page;
3. Check if name of checkbox was previously saved to cookie;
4. If step 3 is `true` set checkbox state to `checked`;
5. Attach `onchange` handler to checkbox;
6. Inside `onchange` handler set or remove cookie depending on checkbox state;
7. Reload page.

Comment: I cannot up vote as I am below poverty line as far as points are concerned. Need 15 to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Use viewstate concept intead of using other cookies logic

Answer (score -2):

Wrap all your logic in

```
AJS.toInit(function ($) {
    // You can use $ instead of AJS.$ here
    ...
});
```

This is Atlassian's equivalent of `$(document).ready(...)` which allows all the Atlassian code to load before you call yours.

Comment: Using AJS.toInit means that you've waited until Atlassian version of jquery has fully loaded before you call it. More here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-use-javascript-in-confluence-313458839.html